# Angularjs-Material md-datepicker renders not correctly

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I have put an md-datepicker in an md-table md-cell. Because of something with my layout my datepicker content is not rendered correctly.

My controller logic:

```
app.controller("testCtrl", function(){
  $scope.authPerson = {};
  $scope.authPerson.dateStart = new Date();
  $scope.authPerson.dateEnd = new Date();
});
```

My view:

```
<md-card>
  <md-card-content>
    <md-table-container>
      <table md-table>
        <tr md-row>
          <td md-cell>
            <md-datepicker ng-model="authPerson.dateStart"></md-datepicker>            
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </md-table-container>
  </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

When I open the datepicker, the container is empty. Screenshot is attached.

[image: md-datepicker render problem]
Thank you in advance for your help.

**Update #1**

I have put the md-datepicker in body and it still doesn't work (works the same way).

```
<body ng-cloak layout="row" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <md-datepicker ng-model="test" ng-disabled="false"></md-datepicker>
</body>
```

AppCtrl:

```
$scope.test = new Date();
```

I think this might be a dependency issue - Moment or something else.

**Update #2**
I have been able to create a plunkr replicating the problem.
https://plnkr.co/edit/4YBK4Eb8LVNeQbH5wIac

Comment: Just found out... when I scroll down, after some time the dates appear.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that your ng-model is authperson.datestart , but your scope variable is authPerson.dateStart
I think it's case sensitive, so it is filling your model with empty data.

Comment: thanks... my bad, copied wrongly... i corrected my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it is a bug reported in Angular Material Github https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10070

This bug occurs when using AngularJS 1.6.0 and Angular Material 1.1.0

Going to revert to AngularJS 1.5.9 until the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Reverting from angular-material version 1.1.1 to version 1.1.0 solved it for me. I use angular version 1.6.1